# Generating automatic user registration number using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

What i wanted to achieve?
I wanted to achieve
{Company Letter}- {Country Code}-{1st Letter of 1st Name}{1st Letter of Last Name}-{000001-999999}
For example:
Company Name: Stack Overflow
Username: Stack Overflow
Country is USA
SO - 001 - SO - 000001

**The Registration numbers will start from ONE when i choose different countries.. For example USA the registration number will start from (000001-999999), for UK (000001-999999) and so on...**

For that i have created a country, state and city model. I have created a custom user model. In the custom user model, i am using country, state, city drop down.

So there is one field called registration numbers.. How can i generate registration number after registering one user..

Code:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Country'), max_length=255, null=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(_('Code'), max_length=10, null=True)
    iso_code_short = models.CharField(_('ISO Code Short'), max_length=2, null=True)
    iso_code_long = models.CharField(_('ISO Code Long'), max_length=3, null=True)
    
def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class State(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('State'), max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = ChainedForeignKey('State', chained_field="country", chained_model_field="country", show_all=False, auto_choose=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('City'), max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Custom User Model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length=100)
    registration_no = models.CharField(_('Registration Number'), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    state = ChainedForeignKey(State, chained_field="country", chained_model_field="country", show_all=False, auto_choose=True)
    city = ChainedForeignKey(City, chained_field="state", chained_model_field="state", show_all=False, auto_choose=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Please guide me..

Comment: Provide more details about your code.

Comment: There are several ways to do it. Can you show what you tried already? Off the top of my head there's a) using the pk of the user model, will be unique, automatically generated, b) upon saving, check last number used and increase by 1, etc.

Comment: @Anna M. Thank you for your reply... i have tried the same thing.. but that is not fulfilling my requirement. I have just updated the code... Please go through that and provide your valuable suggestion.

Comment: @RedWheelbarrow: I have updated the code.. Please guide..

Answer (score 1):

It's a very simple answer:
continue using Django and Python.

You just need a concatenation constructions, something like:
`f"{company.letter}-{country.code}..."` etc.

So create all your models with proper fields and methods, then create the `registration_number` field to store a new registration id and create the value for it on instance's `.save()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... i have tried the same thing.. but not fulfilling my requirement. I have just updated the code... Please go through that and guide me...